# spyOn a function not working - jasmine

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jasmine, ecmascript-6

```
import * as PlanReducer from '../../../reducers/planReducer';

describe('currentPlanReducer()', () => {

   beforeAll(() => {

      spyOn(PlanReducer, 'planReducer').and.callThrough();

   });
});
```

PlanRedcuer is :

```
export default function planReducer(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {....}
```

It throws me an error during test that planRedcuer is not a method, I tried to import other method like that (which was not export default) and it worked. Can any one help me with how I can spy on the function and test it?

Comment: The method `spyOn` is looking for a method named `planReducer` within the object `PlanReducer`.

Comment: Doing this is not a good idea, this only works in Babel because the code is transpiled, in a real ES6 module environment, this code would throw an exception because you cannot mutate the exported values of a module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not exporting the `planReducer` function as `planReducer`, but as `default`. Therefore, in the test you should spy on the `default` property:

```
spyOn(PlanReducer, 'default').and.callThrough();
```

---

Alternatively, you can export the `planReducer` as both `default` and `planReducer`:

```
const planReducer = function planReducer(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {...}
export {planReducer}
export default planReducer
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `import PlanReducer from '../../../reducers/planReducer';`

If you look at the resulting javascript in your planReducer you will see that `'export default function planReducer'` results in '`exports.default = planReducer;'`

And in the resulting javascript in the test/spec `import * as PlanReducer from '../../../reducers/planReducer';` results in `spyOn(planReducer, 'planReducer').and.callThrough();`

But using `import PlanReducer from '../../../reducers/planReducer';` results in `spyOn(app_1.default, 'planReducer').and.callThrough();` which references the default export.